# Find number of positive integers x and y such that 40<=13x+17y<=400

Tags: inequality

Find number of positive integers x and y such that 40<=13x+17y<=400

My attempt

X,y
If x is 1 then y can be between 2,22 means it can take 21 values
Then i tried finding more and tried to find the pattern but cant figure it out.

Comment: Lower bound is easy (1,2) or (2,1). Now $13x \le 400 - 17y$. For every $y$ you can find possible $x$.

Comment: Yes, i was also doing the same but it is very lengthy

Comment: Are you sure about the numbers? The question is lengthy for no reason. For much smaller intervals, the solutions can be worked out easily. See eg, [this](https://brilliant.org/wiki/linear-diophantine-equations-one-equation/).